# ¿Cambiar url sin recargar página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo lograr cambiar la url sin necesidad de recargar la pagina con javascript, y que muestra un loading mientras se muestra la página.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres conseguir? Supongo que quieres recargar la página en respuesta a alguna acción del usuario, ¿cuál es?

Comment: Solo quiero conseguir eso, para que no tenga que precargar toda la pagina una y otra vez, y asi se mas eficiente mi web.
Algo asi como facebook o twitter.

Comment: podrías ponernos un ejemplo de tu código, qué ocurre, y qué quieres que ocurra?

Comment: Me parece que deberías echar un vistazo a los frameworks para hacer SPA o Single Page Applications como React(el de facebook), angular o knockout. Eso te dará lo que quieres para empezar una aplicación nueva.

Comment: supongo que es algo como lo que hace dzone https://dzone.com/articles/9-tips-for-writing-secure-applications-in-aspnet, cuando haces el scroll a otro articulo se cambia la url, sin invocar nagevación

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es modificar la dirección que aparece en la barra del navegador sin tener que recargar la página. Para ello, puedes acceder a la historia de navegación, a través de la API del objeto `History` del navegador, en concreto su instancia en `window.history`.

Lee la documentación en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Por ejemplo, si en la página `dominio.com/fulano.html` se ejecuta este código

```
history.pushState(null, "", "mengano.html");
```

la barra de direcciones pasará a contener `dominio.com/mengano.html`